# How to get how many time a table appears on two (or more) other different tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have to get how many members and how many administrators a group has my tables are the following:

(I know that group is a selected word but it's for the sake of the example)

- `Group` (groupId, groupName)
- `Members`(memberId, groupId)
- `Admins`(adminId, groupId)

What I have is the follwing

```
select count(m.memberId) as Members
       count(a.memberId) as Admins
from Group g
join Admins a
on a.groupId=g.groupId
join Members m
on m.groupId=g.groupId
where g.goupId=1
```

I know the where clause seems odd but I'm making this to fit it on a stored procedure, this is just shorter and makes the question a little bit more to the point

This works like a charm when I only get the number of members, when I try to add Admins the query returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (select count(*) from Members where goupId=1) as Members,
       (select count(*) from admins  where goupId=1) as Admins
```

Comment: Imma try this out and confirm your answer, thanks friendo

Comment: can you add something and tell my why does my solution not work?

Comment: Because the 2 joins require both condition to be true.  You could use a left but this is a better solution to the stated question.